# SharePoint 2013 Online o365 and Very large external data for a Data dictionary solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki, xml, data, xml-viewer-web-part

We have a very large SQL data source. That SQL database in on Prem and really secured tight - no update allowed.  It's one of many data sources we plan to use to produce an enterprise wide Definition library.  This product in front of that one SQL database has an extract feature to produce related XML files.  It produces 1000s of related XML files that you can use to navigate 3 or 4 levels deep.

If our hope was to leverage SharePoint Online as the front end of this Definition library enabling users Search and appending data that would not be overlaid by updates what SharePoint limitation should we consider?

Starting with:

1. Wiki and other built in Apps can't connect to external data source
2. Search will not index SQL Views.
3. I'm not sure anything in SPO facilitates related XML files
4. What  Search indexing of XML files look like?
5. Can XML files be fit into a Wiki
6. What happens if we try to load 50k items into a list or Wiki?

Is trying to implement this in SharePoint Online just going to require a lot customization and interface work?